# Dynamically set tab in AngularUI Bootstrap (ui.bootstrap.tabs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the tabs directive of AngularUI Bootstrap with dynamically generated tabs.

```
<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
<uib-tabset active="activeForm">
  <uib-tab  index="$index" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" >
    <uib-tab-heading>{{tab.title}}</uib-tab-heading>
    {{tab.content}}
  </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

When the tabs array is changed the UI Tabs get amended accordingly but no active tab is set (although I explicitly do set in in the controller)

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:'Dynamic Title 1', content:'Dynamic content 1' },
    { title:'Dynamic Title 2', content:'Dynamic content 2' },
    { title:'Dynamic Title 3', content:'Dynamic content 3' },
    { title:'Dynamic Title 4', content:'Dynamic content 4' }
  ];

  $scope.changeTabs = function(){
         $scope.tabs = [
       { title:'Dynamic Title 5', content:'Dynamic content 5' },
       { title:'Dynamic Title 6', content:'Dynamic content 6' }
     ];
     $scope.activeForm = 0; //Not working, how can I select tab dynamically?
  };

  $scope.model = {
    name: 'Tabs'
  };
});
```

Can anybody tell me what I am missing?

See here for Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ow7Cd1eidCgaLNOhX1Vl

Thanks in advance
Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the setting of activeForm in a $timeout:

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.activeForm = 0;
});
```

This is a known issue - https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5805

Updated [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/kcyGfBEh3tN6SqPLewsc?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Hey here is code need to change

```
$timeout(function(){
 $scope.activeForm = 0; //Not working, how can I select tab dynamically? 
},0);
```

This will trigger digest cycle and your code will work